# codeigniter flashdata never arrive in my controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have this code in my view:

```
if (($faq_cat['categoryphoto'] !="")|| ($faq_cat['categoryphoto'] != NULL)) {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('tablename', 'faq_categories');
       $this->session->keep_flashdata('tablename');
       $this->session->set_flashdata('recordid', $faq_cat['catid']);
       $this->session->set_flashdata('fieldname', 'catid');
       $this->session->set_flashdata('fieldToUpdate', 'categoryphoto');
       $this->session->set_flashdata('dpage', 'faq/editFaqCategory');
       echo anchor('faqcategories/updateOneField', 'Delete Current Photo?');
}
```

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
    public function updateOneField() 
    {  

        $tablename = $this->session->flashdata('tablename');
        $id = $this->session->flashdata('recordid');
        $fieldname = $this->session->flashdata('fieldname');
        $fieldToUpdate = $this->session->flashdata('fieldToUpdate');
        echo "<br />table name is: " .$tablename;
        echo $id;
        echo $fieldname;
        echo $fieldToUpdate;
        die();
        $this->load->model('faqCategoriesModel');
        $this->faqCategoriesModel->save(array($fieldToUpdate => ''), $id);        
        $catid = $id;
        $this->displayEditFaqCategoryForm($catid);
    } // end of function updateOneField
```

Any attempt to read the data sent trough the flash data is failing. All flashdata variables comes empty. I load  the session in my autoload.php file. This very same code, works in another CI application. Can anyone spot what i am doing wrong? I tried to use `$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');` both in my view and controller, without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just give up and I set up my variables in the userdata, like this:

```
$newdata = array(
    'tablename'  => 'faq_categories',
    'recordid'     => $faq_cat['catid'],
    'fieldname' => 'catid',
    'fieldToUpdate' => 'categoryphoto',
    'dpage' => 'faqcategories/editFaqCategory'
    );
```

Cheers